# Why does the Monero GUI wallet not save the daemon flags?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

The Monero GUI wallet is not saving daemon flags on my system, Ubuntu 18.04.

Also, there is no more *start daemon* button.

Comment: Which version of the GUI are you running?

Comment: Are other settings saving?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP. Using gui version 0.13.0.4 (Qt 5.7.0) on Linux Mint 18.3.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5963)

Comment: @Eric - This will be fixed in the upcoming GUI v0.14 release, which should be out soon.